# Which free online books cover this curriculum?

Tags: undergraduate-education, textbooks

I am teaching mathematics at a Danish Business College, and some of my classes belong to the international IBB-programme. However, the college has no English textbook material for my subject, so I have to find it myself. Otherwise I will have to keep the lessons in English but using a Danish textbook which I find far from ideal.

This autumn, I must teach them:

- Percentage, index numbers
- The base terminoligy about functions such as vertical line test, domains and codomains, graphing by hand and interpreting a graph visually, zeros and variation of signs
- Linear equations, linear functions and piecewise linear functions
- Descriptive statistics for numerical data, discrete and continuous. This should include mean, variance, bar charts, histograms, ogives, and box- and whiskers plots
- Linear and exponential models and regressions

Can someone help me determining a strategy for finding such material? Or better yet, does someone have an online reference to some material I could use?

I found a nice one on [prealgebra](http://mathrev.redwoods.edu/PreAlgText/), but it only covers basic operations with numbers and letters together with simple percentages and graphing linear equations.

Comment: There are several collections of no-cost mathematics books/texts around, Google knows all. E.g. [at Georgia Tech](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/textbooks/onlinebooks.html), [at MagMath](http://magmath.com/problems/math/textbooks), the books from [Trillia](http://trillia.com). Look also for online courses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm growing fond of the OpenStax open-source books. I haven't used them in class yet, but they've recently gotten good enough where I'd be happy to do so.

One option is to use bits from two of their books. College Algebra Ch. 2, 3, 4, 6 (equations, functions, linear functions, exponential functions), and Introductory Statistics Ch. 2, 12 (descriptive statistics, linear regression) would seem to cover most of your needs. The initial percentage discussion you'd have to fill in yourself (or from your Prealgebra book).

https://openstaxcollege.org/books